# Logic calculations with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a question in regards to php calculations.
i am restructuring a text based game. 
the game has two "native players" right now. they get inserted periodically by a cron file. 
the insert is :

**//player 1 Login id = 54**

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO {$game}_ships (ship_name,login_name,shipclass,class_name,class_name_abbr,fighters,max_fighters,max_shields,cargo_bays,mine_rate_metal,mine_rate_fuel,config,size,upgrades,move_turn_cost,point_value,location,login_id
    ) values(   'Three 7','A','8','name','WM','4773','4773','8353','2003','5','45','bs:dt:ot','6','99','19','10',FLOOR(RAND() * 298 + 2),'54')");
```

player two has the same insert, only the player id is different. **lets say 44**.

they get inserted in random locations **FLOOR(RAND() * 298 + 2)** which vary from 2 to 300.

i want to create an *AI* in the game by selecting ships from these two players that are in the same system, comparing the fighter counts and deleting from the database the weakest.

So far i have:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `{$game}_ships` WHERE `login_id` = 54 AND 54 AND `location` = 234");
```

but im having some problems as to the rest.

Any comments or help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: i selected **`location` = 234"** arbitrarily.

Comment: How are you measuring "weakness"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you a list of locations where both players 54 and 44 have ships:

```
SELECT distinct p1s.location
FROM `{$game}_ships` p1s JOIN `{$game}_ships` p2s ON p1s.location=p2s.location
WHERE p1s.login_id=54 AND p2s.login_id=44;
```

And this query will delete the weakest ship of player 54 or 44 in location 234:

```
DELETE from `{$game}_ships`
WHERE login_id IN (54, 44) AND location=234
ORDER BY fighters LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Your script is a lot more simpler. i like this version as well. Thank you fellas.

Comment: Do us a favor and upvote and/or accept our answers, unless you are still waiting for a better one. Thanks!

Comment: i did upvote both for your effort. this is not an easy task. Although the Delete function doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Or is it simply deleting nothing? Or is it deleting the wrong one?

Comment: its not deleting anything. the script runs fine without errors.

Comment: Hmm, well, you can always change it to a SELECT and run it in mysql console to find out what is going on... Perhaps you didn't replace 234 with a variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through all locations and check each one, to see if it has at least one ship from each player; if it does, then you destroy the weaker. See:

```
for ($i = 2; $i < 300; $i++) {
  $p1 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT count(*) AS 'q' FROM `{$game}_ships` WHERE `login_id` = 54 AND `location` = " . $i));
  $p2 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT count(*) AS 'q' FROM `{$game}_ships` WHERE `login_id` = 44 AND `location` = " . $i));
  if ($p1['q'] > 0 && $p2['q'] > 0) {
    //Get the first ship; if you want, can select a ship randomly
    $p1s = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `{$game}_ships` WHERE `login_id` = 54 AND `location` = ".i));
    $p2s = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `{$game}_ships` WHERE `login_id` = 44 AND `location` = ".i));
    //Here you compare $p1s and $p2s, and check which one is stronger. I am using the 'fighters' value, but you can change it if I misunderstood you
    if ($p1s['fighters'] > $ps2['fighters'])
      mysql_query ("DELETE FROM `{$game}_ships` WHERE `ship_name` = " + $ps2['ship_name']);
    else //Not checking for ties here, you can add it too
      mysql_query ("DELETE FROM `{$game}_ships` WHERE `ship_name` = " + $ps1['ship_name']);
  }
}
```

I am not sure if I completely understood you, but I hope this is at least a part of what you want.

Comment: that is most impressive.  although it doesnt seem to recognize .i on $p1 and $p2.

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake... It should be $i.